# iMac issues: indicates hard disk needs replacing and can't get through AHT, should I do any other tests?

Tags: hard-drive, imac, disk-utility, startup

I have a long out of warranty/AppleCare iMac12,2 that meets me with an Apple logo and progress bar on boot, and after a few minutes simply shuts off w/o booting to the system. I did try running Apple Hardware Test, and it simply freezes 3 minutes and 27 minutes into the test, every time I run it.

Booting in recovery and running Disk Utility on the volume gave me the message: "Error: Disk Utility can't repair this disk.Back up as many of your files as possible, reformat the disk, and restore your backed-up files."

From this point I did try booting in single user and running fsck and it met me with an error that it could not verify the disk and did not proceed beyond this point.

Obviously the hard disk needs replacing. Should I be OK just replacing the hard disk or should I be running other tests to make sure that there are no other issues with the computer prior to replacing the disk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn’t necessarily need a hard drive. Have you erased it and tried installing an OS?

You’ll need an external bootable OS for this on 2011 era hardware.

Only if you can’t get that working would you need a repair. A failing disk usually doesn’t cause shutdowns without logging a prodigious amount of IO errors and any technician should be able to read the SMART statistics to conclude the drive is malfunctioning or error free. If you need help locating a trained shop, try https://locate.apple.com

Best of luck with getting this repaired! (But only if it needs it)

Comment: Wanted to come back and mark this as the correct answer. You were right - all I needed to do was back up the machine, fix hard disk errors, reinstall the OS and everything ended up being fine. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Note that although correct, about a month later I am back to square one with this issue. It is either the hard driver at this point or something else. All of the exact symptoms as the original problem posted above. I have another machine I use in the meantime, but if I do repair it I will update this thread as to what the issue ended up being, and what happened.

Comment: In the end, I had to get the hard drive replaced. I did this back in 2021. Took it to the apple store and the drive totally failed their testing - that's how I knew to replace. Thanks.